# Swift: Expression type casting in callback

Tags: ios, swift, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to use a callback in swift, passing it an Array of Bait Objects and returning nothing.
Here's my code:

```
TBParseHelper.getBaitsForFeedWithCallback(callback: { (baits: Array<Bait>) -> Void in
            if (baits) {

            } else {

            }
        })
```

It's giving me an error saying that it `Cannot convert the expression's type '(callback: (Array<Bait>) -> Void!)' to type '((([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) -> Void'` on the first line. I've tried putting a number of different combinations of `?`'s and `!`'s to no real effect.

Comment: Please add the `TBParseHelper.getBaitsForFeedWithCallback` function signature to your question. It looks like an issue with the typing on the `bait` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TBParseHelper.getBaitsForFeedWithCallback(callback: { (baits) -> Void in
        if (baits) {

        } else {

        }
    })
```

http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/